# More same id´s in document.getElementById("")

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I have html file with 157 id´s

```
id="name"
```

and i need change style property "display" from "none" to "block" by click on **one checkbox** 
On that i have this script :

```
function nms(){
      if (document.getElementById("name").style.display === 'block') document.getElementById("name").style.display = 'none';
      else {document.getElementById("name").style.display === 'block';}}
```

which change this property in **every single** that **id**.

**I need to change it on every not the first id.
I just found this :**

```
$("[id=yourID]").
```

i need to implement that code to my checkbox, onclick function which do on the first click display : block and on second display : none.

but it didn´t work for me and i can´t use **document.getElementByClassName** because i need to change display property.

Thanks or your help, i don´t know how to make it run :-(

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: Your markup is invalid, so the behavior of the JavaScript is undefined.  `id`s need to be unique (as their name implies).  Fix the markup first.

Comment: The entire point of ID is that it's unique, use a Class for repeatable selection attributes.

Comment: I is bad practice use the same ID in multiple elements, use `class` attribute

Comment: jq shortcuts selectors, but `document.querySelectorAll("[id=yourID]").` should work.

Comment: How can i have multiple that element without same id, where i can change Display property of all that elements ?

Comment: @THERimaniaTHERimania: If you want to group multiple elements to be selectable, that's what a `class` is for.  Note that any given element can have more than one `class` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `id` you might want to use some other attribute. a class common on all HTML element will be a good idea. If your markup is something like below

```
<div class="name abc"></div>
<div class="name xyz"></div>
<div class="name pqr"></div>
<div class="name hjk"></div>
```

then you can write javascript code to set `display:block` for all of them as shown below

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
if (elements != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].style.display === "block") {
            elements[i].style.display = "none";
        } else {
            elements[i].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** In HTML it is not valid to have same id for multiple DOM elements

**EDIT:** added if check in loop to allow toggle

Comment: It works perectly thanks a lot, but i need to implement that code to my **checkbox**,  **onclick** function which do on the first click **display : block** and on second  **display : none**. Can you help me with that ? I try to make that but without succes. Thanks for your help, i appreciate it.

Comment: check the new code now after edit

Comment: There are no words that I'm able to thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it you think you cannot use `getElementsByClassName`? Changing the `display` property is independent from how you select elements.

Comment: Itry it and it didnt work